# Internet Explorer Page Break On Textarea

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, print-preview

In our application, we have a table controlling the alignment of form fields (bad, I know, but I can't change it). The customer reported that they do not like how Internet Explorer will insert a page break on Print Preview in a way such that the field label (first `<td>`) is on a different page than the field value (second `<td`).

As an example, do a Print Preview of the following and size up (e.g. 200%).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing</title>
        <style>
            td {
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>       
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    First cell.
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="30" cols="50">Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. Second cell. </textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "First cell." display appears on page 1 and the textarea appears on page 2. See [snapshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbNsr.jpg).

Is there any way to force the two `<td>` elements to always appear on the same page?

Comment: I am on IE8, but ideally the solution would work on all the recent ones.

Comment: can't reproduce the described behavior, see [a snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/yUbmf.png?1). can you provide a demo or a reliable test case reproducing this?

Comment: @EliranMalka Not sure why it doesn't work for you. Updated the question to have my exact testing code and added a link to my snapshots.

Comment: Is that stray double quote in your styles actually part of your code or some copy/paste mixup?

Comment: Maybe reduve the line-height by adding a print class to the textarea / td.

Comment: please enclose the CSS code, it's a key component for understanding what's going on.

Comment: @EliranMalka The code in my question is literally what I am running for testing. It is having the issue.